# MPRemoteCommandCenter and Play Pause Update with the AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: ios

I am currently using `AVSpeechSynthesizer` for Text to Speech. Category used for the playback is `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` and `AVAudioSession` is set to **Active YES**.

During the start of the play, **`[TTS]`** `TTSPlaybackCreate` unable to initialize `dynamics: -3000` in the *Xcode* console. When i pause the playback i get `[TTS] _BeginSpeaking: couldn't begin playback`.

My major issue is `MPRemoteCommandCenter` doesn't get updated to *pause* when **`TTS`** stopped.

For Stop functionality, I am using this code;

```
BOOL speechStopped =  [self.ttsSpeechSynthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
if(!speechStopped) {
    [self.ttsSpeechSynthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryWord];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had Airplay connected to an Airplay station.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue after updating iOS to the latest version on my phone.
I spent much time trying to understand why my app stopped talking using TextToSpeech while all worked before and code seemed ok.
Siri was talking aloud fine, and the sound in other apps worked as well
Mine was giving no error message in the code and the following in the device log:

Error (730) / LearnByHeart.iOS(TTSSpeechBundle): TTSPlaybackCreate unable to initialize dynamics: -3000

Rebooting the phone did not help.

As funny as it is, all got resolved by turning the physical sound button off and back on.

Hope this saves someone a day